# How to find more than two words in a file using python

Tags: python, regex, raw-input

I have a file named `test.txt`. Inside the file `test.txt` reads:

> "Drawings me opinions returned absolute in. Otherwise therefore sex did are unfeeling something. Certain be ye amiable by exposed so. To celebrated estimating excellence do. Coming either suffer living her gay theirs. Furnished do otherwise daughters contented conveying attempted no. Was yet general visitor present hundred too brother fat arrival. Friend are day own either lively new. "

I'm trying to grab two words from this file, for e.g the words "celebrated" and "atemted".
Here's what I did:

```
word = raw_input("what do you want to search ")

for i in open('test.txt'):
   if word in i.split():
```

I also tried this:

```
word = raw_input("what do you want to search ").split()

for i in open('test.txt'):
   if word[0] and word[1] in i.split():
```

But I can't get the results I'm looking for. Because if I give just one input in the `raw_input` statement it gives me an error, because the second value, which is `word[1]`, is not set. Is there a different way to search for two or more words?

Answer (score 2):

```
if word[0] in i.split() and word[1] in i.split():
```

better to put `i.split()` in a variable

```
i_split = i.split()
if word[0] in i_split and word[1] in i_split:
```

You can use `all` too

```
i_split = i.split()
if all(word[i] in i_split for i in (0,1)):
```

better get rid of `i`

```
i_split = i.split()
if all(w in i_split for w in word):
```

You might get an improvement by making `i_split` a set

```
i_split = set(i.split())
if all(w in i_split for w in word):
```

Now use a context manager for the file

```
word = raw_input("what do you want to search ").split()

with open('test.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        line_split = set(line.split())
        if all(w in line_split for w in word):
            ...
```

If you mean to search the whole file instead of line by line

```
word = raw_input("what do you want to search ").split()

with open('test.txt') as fin:      
    fin_split = set(fin.split())
    if all(w in fin_split for w in word):
        ...
```

Comment: You are lloking for both words in the same line!

Comment: Isn't that what the OP is doing? It's trivial to switch to `fin.read()`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use these functions:**

```
def find_words_in_file(file_path, words):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        contents = f.read()  # should only be used for small files
    results = {word:True if word in contents else False for word in words}
    return results

def get_user_words():
    user_input = raw_input("provide some words then press enter:\n")
    return user_input.split()

def main():
    file_path = "your/file/path/here"
    words = get_user_words()
    return find_words_in_file(file_path, words)
```

**For example, I have used the same logic below:**

```
words = ['celebrated', 'atemted']

contents = """
Drawings me opinions returned absolute in. 
Otherwise therefore sex did are unfeeling something.
Certain be ye amiable by exposed so. To celebrated estimating excellence do. 
Coming either suffer living her gay theirs. 
Furnished do otherwise daughters contented conveying attempted no. 
Was yet general visitor present hundred too brother fat arrival. 
Friend are day own either lively new. 
"""

results = {word:True if word in contents else False for word in words}
print results
```

**Results:**

```
>>> 
{'celebrated': True, 'atemted': False}
```